# Circumventing Ruby's scope gates when defining class methods

Tags: ruby

I have a class `A`, which I would like to anonymously extend and add a class method to the child class. E.g.:

```
class A
end

Class.new A do
  def self.new_class_method
    puts 'I am a class method'
  end
end.new_class_method

=> I am a class method
```

The above example works well, unless you want to access some variables outside of the `def self.new_class_method` block. E,g,

```
greeting = 'hello'

Class.new A do
  def self.new_class_method
    puts greeting + ' I am a class method'
  end
end.new_class_method

=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `greeting'
```

I am using Ruby 1.8.7, which is sad because I believe Ruby 1.9+ contains an analog to `define_method` which adds a class method. Does anyone have a work around for 1.8.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested the below in **Ruby 1.8.7** :-

```
greeting = 'hello'

class A
end

Class.new A do 
  meta_klass = class << self; self ;end
  meta_klass.send(:define_method, :new_class_method) do
    puts greeting + ' I am a class method'
  end
end.new_class_method
# >> hello I am a class method
```

As Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't support [`Object#singleton_class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class), I used `meta_klass = class << self; self ;end`. This method is available since *1.9.2*, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use extend() to pry open an object's singleton class.  Calling extend(module) adds the methods in the module to the calling object's(i.e. the receiver's) singleton class.  So if you call extend(module) when self=A, i.e. inside class A, then the module's methods will be inserted into A's singleton class, and the methods in A's singleton class are also known as class methods of A:

```
class A
end

greeting = "hello"

Class.new(A) do 

  extend(
    Module.new do
      define_method(:greet) do
        puts greeting
      end
    end
  )

end.greet

--output:--
hello
```

And you can rewrite that like this (although then it's not as tricky):

```
class A
end

greeting = "hello"

Class.new(A) do 

  m =  Module.new do
    define_method(:greet) do
      puts greeting
    end
  end

  extend(m)

end.greet
```

...which isn't much different than:

```
class A
end

greeting = "hello"

m =  Module.new do
  define_method(:greet) do
    puts greeting
  end
end

Class.new(A) do 
  extend(m)
end.greet
```

...which moves the closure out of the class, and doesn't seem very tricky at all because it only opens up two scope gates instead of three.

Also note, extend() is a public method, so it doesn't require the trickery of a private method, i.e. where you can't specify an explicit receiver, so you have to create a context in which self is the object you want to call the private method on.  In other words, you can specify an explicit receiver for extend().  How about the class that is returned by Class.new(A)?

```
class A
end

greeting = "hello"

Class.new(A).extend(
  Module.new do
    define_method(:greet) do
      puts greeting
    end
  end
).greet


--output:--
hello
```

Hey, tacking on ".greet" there works! Uh oh, that has the makings of a one liner:

```
class A
end

greeting = "hello"

Class.new(A).extend(Module.new {define_method(:greet) {puts greeting} }).greet

--output:--
hello
```

Yeech!

Answer (score 1):

More generally,

```
class A
end

class Object
  def meta_def name, &blk
    (class << self; self; end).instance_eval { define_method name, &blk }
  end
end

greeting = 'hello'

Class.new A do
  meta_def :new_class_method do
    puts greeting + ' I am a class method'
  end
end.new_class_method
  #=> hello I am a class method
```

If you find this useful, don't thank me, thank some [lucky stiff](http://whytheluckystiff.net/articles/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html) (which I saw mentioned by [Jay Fields](http://ruby.dzone.com/news/dynamically-created-methods-ru)).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but changing Greeting to uppercase (making it a constant) would work...

```
class A
end

Greeting = 'hello'

Class.new A do
  def self.new_class_method
    puts Greeting + ' I am a class method'
  end
end.new_class_method
```

Comment: I don't think that's the point of Max' question. He used a string as example, but what he wants to do is incorporate the value of a variable or method in the current scope in the method that he is defining.